# Getting errors with dependent dropdown lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in *SQL Server*,

```
country_Id          country
1                   India
2                   Australia
3                   Netherlands
```

the 2nd table is states

```
state_Id           country_Id      state
1                   2              abc
2                   2              xyz
3                   3              pqr
4                   1              lmn
5                   1              rst
```

On page load country automatically come in `dropdown1` and When I select *Australia* in the first drop down, in 2nd drop down `abc` and `xyz` will be shown.

I did but I am getting a *bad query* error.

What is the correct query?

My code is:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT state FROM table_state ,table_country where country = '"
            + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() 
            + "' on table_state.country_Id = table_country.country_Id", con);
    con.Open();
    ds1 = new DataSet();
    adap.Fill(ds1);
    DropDownList2.DataSource = ds1;
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "state";
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "state"
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Error is "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'."

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your code `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` method

```
 adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT state FROM table_state where country_Id = '" 
                         + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "'", con);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query in the argument should be something like (from what I gather):

```
    "SELECT distinct a.state FROM table_state a inner join table_country b on
    a.country_Id = b.country_Id
    where a.country = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `DropDownList1.DataValueField = "country_Id"` and just use the following, no need for joining.
this is simple

```
adap = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT state FROM table_state where country_Id = '{0}'",DropDownList1.SelectedValue), con);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not good practice to use drop-down value direct to query, you can use parameter in SqlDataAdapter like:

```
  adap = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct a.state 
                              FROM table_state a 
                                 inner join table_country b
                                      on a.country_Id = b.country_Id
                                             where a.country = @Country");
  adap.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country",DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: I wrote this Query....Its working fine.but After selection in dropdown, page is refreshing (due to autopost back is true)..what ever i select in dropdown its coming India with its respective state only..              Query is---------------------------. string srt = "SELECT distinct state FROM table_state inner join table_country on table_country.country_Id = table_state.country_Id where table_country.country = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"; adap = new SqlDataAdapter(srt, con);

Comment: Please make sure correct country is passed to the database using SQL profiler.

Comment: Every time only 1 country is passing in "str"...However i selected another countries also.